# Github private repo safe from scrapers?

Tags: privacy, git, github

I have a question about the security of private repo's on Github. Assume you use HTTPS authenticated against SAML SSO to fetch and push changes to remote. Could an outside adversary scrape the files from the display page if they know the URL?

Comment: Why not try this yourself instead of asking us? You know your own repo's URL, so try accessing it while logged out and see what happens.

Comment: If you are able to access its contents, you might get huge bounty from Github :)

Answer (score 1):

Someone who does not have access to a private repository sees a 404 Page not found error. So no, if an outsider knows the url he can not scrape the contents of your github repository page.

Answer (score 0):

Not safe from Github itself, they will scrape it for building models for copilot if soon enough. Doesn't even matter what license you put there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).